# Add error if no vowel detected in input string

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that is supposed to take an input and output what the most common vowel is as seen here:

```
while True:

    string = input("Enter a line of text: ")
    vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"

    x = Counter(c for c in string.upper() if c in vowel)
    most = {k: x[k] for k in x if x[k] == max(x.values())}

    for i in most:
        vowel = i
        y = most [i]
        print("The most frequently occurring vowel in the string is: " ,vowel, "with ,y, "occurrences.")

    break
```

But I can't figure out how to have an error message if there are no vowels in the input. I have tried:

```
if vowel != string:
    print("Error, no vowels were detected in the user input.")
    continue
```

But this doesn't work. If I put it before the section where it outputs the most common vowel, then no matter what is input the error message shows and the input starts again. If I put it after that, then the vowels are detected and most common is printed, but it continues to display the error message and restart the input instead of breaking the program.

How can I write the error so that it looks at the input to see if there are any vowels in there and displays the error if there aren't any?

Comment: Consider either dropping `.upper()` from `c for c in string.upper() if c in vowel` OR dropping lower case letters from `vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"`. Keeping both is a waste.

Comment: This is full code ? or there is Counter function anywhere ?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I do not think this question is a duplicate of one of the two questions mentioned by you: The user already has a `Counter` of vowels (see `x`). Suggesting that the user start all over again to check that there are vowels is wasteful. My answer provides something new in the context of this specific code: no answer in the questions pointed to by you provide an answer that takes advantage of `Counter`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a counter of all vowels (`x`) it would be a waste to check (again) whether user input contains vowels. You could simply check that `x` is empty (i.e., that it has not counted any vowels):

```
if not x:
    print("Error, no vowels were detected in the user input.")
    continue
```

In addition, consider either dropping `.upper()` from `c for c in string.upper() if c in vowel` OR dropping lower case letters from `vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"`. Keeping both is unnecessary.